# iframe height and scrollbar is not working in IE11

Tags: jsp

I have following iframe attributes

```
<iframe ID="navBody" style="width:expression(document.body.clientWidth); height:expression(document.body.clientHeight - umiLogo.height)" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="/Test/access/navigation.do"></iframe>
```

Initially nothing was displayed in IE11(Work fine in IE9 & IE10). Then I added compatibility meta tag `<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=8' />`
After adding this, I got the page with half of the contents, means the iframe height was not 100%. I can say it was around 30%. Then I changed the height like "height:500px", and the page displayed properly. But scrollbar didnt come.

Please help me, how can I get the height and scrollbars without changing the iframe attributes

Comment: set style="overflow: auto;" scrolling="true" to iframe.

Comment: Sorry, scrolling="yes"

Comment: I also came across with such problem. The work-around was to open iframe in div based popup.

Comment: I tried with div too. I guess the problem with the metatag I used. For the above metatag, page is not coming in IE9. Please help what is the meta tag to be used that should be compatible with all the IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try overflow: auto attribute in css.